# Is having a fine-grained package structure a good or a bad thing?

Tags: java

I recently looked at a Java application which had a very fine-grained package structure. Many packages only contained one or two classes and many sub packages. Also many packages contained more sub packages than actual classes.

Is this a good or a bad thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IMO, it is a bad thing, though not a real show-stopper in terms of maintainability.

The disadvantages are that it makes classes harder to find, and that it makes the package names more verbose.  The former applies more when you are not using an IDE.

It could be argued that it helps modularization in conjunction with "package private" scoping.  But conversely, you could also argue that over-packagization actually does the opposite; i.e. forcing you to use `public` where you wouldn't have had to if you'd been less fine-grained / pedantic.

Answer (score 8):

The actual number of types that end up in one particular package is not that important. It is how you arrive at your package structure.

Things like abstraction ("what" instead of "how", essentially "public" API), coupling (the degree of how dependent a package is on other packages) and cohesion (how interrelated is the functionality in one package) are more important.

Some guidelines for package design (mostly from [Uncle Bob](http://butunclebob.com/)) are for example:

- Packages should form reusable and releasable modules
- Packages should be focussed for good reusability
- Avoid cyclic dependencies between packages
- Packages should depend only on packages that change less often
- The abstraction of a package should be in proportion to how often it changes

Do not try to flesh out an entire package structure from scratch (You Are Not Going To Need It). Instead let it evolve and refactor often. Look at the `import` section of your Java sources for inspiration on moving types around. Don't be distracted by packages that contain only one or a few types.

Answer (score 6):

I think finer grained package structure is a good thing. The main reason is it can help minimize your dependencies. But be careful... if you break things up too much that actually belong together, you will end up with circular dependencies!

As a rule of thumb, I usually have an interface (or group of related interfaces) in a package. And in subpackages I will have implementations of those interfaces (instead of having all the implementations in the same package). That way a client can just depend on the interface and implementation of interest... and not all the other stuff they don't need.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

It is subjective, of course, but I generally prefer to decide my packages in a way they would contain at least 3-4 classes, but not more than about 13-15. It makes understanding better, while not cluttering the project. For others it might be different, though.
In case a package grows more than 13-15 classes, a subpackage is asking to emerge.

Answer (score 2):

A package is a unit of encapsulation.

Ideally, it exposes a public API via interface(s) and hides implementation detail in package private classes.

The size of the package is therefore the number of classes needed to implement the public API.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the magical number 7 +/- 2. Within physiological circles it has been shown that this is a basic limit on our ability to comprehend a given set of things. How much we can keep in short term memory and process at the same time before our brains need to start swapping. It is not a bad rule of thumb I've found when coding, ie once a package starts getting bigger than 10 classes it is time to think seriously about splitting it up, but below 5 packages it is really not worth it. Also applies well to things like menu organisation. See [Millers paper](http://www.musanim.com/miller1956/), or google.

Answer (score 0):

When writing from scratch my way is to begin all classes in the root package (com.example.app1). When there is a certain amount of interrelated classes that "do a whole thing" is time to create a package. After some time developing helper classes may go to a **generic package** (ex. com.example.app1.misc, com.example.app1.utils) to unload the root package.

So i try to keep clean the root package.

Fine-grain is not bad but as other said often refactoring produce a compact package structure.